# Warnings in a homework problem C++

Tags: c++, class, function

Getting two warning when i run this program and i can't figure out how to stop this from happening. Any help would be appreciated!

warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions

Is the warning I'm getting for 2 lines in the extract_word function.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class StringModify {

    public:

    void get_data();
    //takes a line of input from the user

    string& extract_word(string& a);
    //extracts each word from the input line

    string& reverse_word(string& s);
    //returns a string which is reverse of s

    void rev();

    void swap(char& v1, char& v2);
    //interchanges value of v1 and v2

    void append(const string& reverse_word);
    //puts together each reversed word with whitespaces to get formatted_line

    void display();
    //diss both input line and formatted_line

    private:
    string origional_string;   //original string
    string formatted_string; //formatted string
    string word;

};


int main() {
    StringModify data1;
    //data1 becomes the call for class StringModify

    data1.get_data();
    // Exicution of get_data in class StringModify
    data1.rev();
    // Exicution of rev in class StringModify
    data1.display();
    // Exicution of display in class StringModify

    return 0; }

void StringModify::get_data() {
    cout << "Enter the string: ";
    getline(cin, origional_string); }

string& StringModify::extract_word(string& a) {
    size_t position = a.find(" ");

    if(position != -1)
    {
        word = a.substr(0, position);
        a.erase (0, position + 1);
    }

    else
    {
        word = a;
        a = "";
    }

    return word; }

string& StringModify::reverse_word(string& s) {
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length() / 2; i++)
    {
        swap(s[i], s[s.length() - 1 - i]);
    }

    return s; }

void StringModify::rev() {
    string copy = origional_string;

    while (!copy.empty())
    {
        append(reverse_word(extract_word(copy)));
    } }

void StringModify::swap(char& v1, char& v2) {
    char temp = v1;
    v1 = v2;
    v2 = temp; }

void StringModify::append(const string& reverse_word) {
    formatted_string += reverse_word + " "; }

void StringModify::display() {
    cout << "\nThe original string: "
         << origional_string << "\n"
         << "\nThe formatted string: "
         << formatted_string << "\n"; }
```

Comment: It's *really* helpful to include the actual warnings when asking for explanation of them.

Comment: why are `swap`, `reverse_word` and `extract_word` class methods when they don't touch the class members at all ? Also note the existence of http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You assign the result of `a.find(" ")` to a `size_t`.  `size_t` is an unsigned type; it can never have a negative value.

Note that that does not mean the comparison will never be true.  The `-1` will be converted to be unsigned so the comparison can be performed (this is part of what are called the usual arithmetic conversions).  When you convert `-1` to be unsigned, it yields the largest value representable by the unsigned type.  So, if `find()` returns the largest possible `size_t`, then the comparison will yield true.

To resolve the warning, you should compare against `std::string::npos`, which is the value returned from `find()` if the element is not found.

Comment: And what should i do for the error I'm getting in reverse_word. s.length() is the problem.

Comment: you want to use size_t for that instead of int.

Comment: @Alec:  If you are getting a signed/unsigned conversion, make `i` unsigned.

Comment: @James warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions| is what I'm getting for that one as well but i cant un assign i or it will not know where to start the loop because i will have a random variable right?

Comment: @Alec:  `s.length()` is unsigned which means that `s.length() / 2` is unsigned.  `i` is an `int` and is thus signed.  To resolve the warning you need to either change the declaration of `i` to make it `unsigned` (or `size_t` or `std::string::size_type` or some unsigned type) or use a cast to convert the right side to be signed:  `(int)(s.length() / 2)`.  The former method is far better because it doesn't require a cast and expresses your intent much more clearly.

Answer (score 4):

`size_t` is an unsigned type and can therefore "never" be equal to `-1`. The reason I have `never` inside quotes is because it may well compare equal to `-1` in some circumstances but that's only because either it or the `-1` has been morphed into the other data type.

`string::find` is [documented](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) to return [`string::npos`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/) if the string can't be found and *that's* what you should compare your return value with (it's the `size_t` equivalent of `-1` anyway but done in such a way that you won't get warnings).

Answer (score 4):

Use string::npos instead of -1

Answer (score 2):

[size_t](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstddef/size_t/) is an unsigned integer and you are comparing it to -1.  You need to change it's type to something else.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code:

```
    size_t position = a.find(" ");

    if(position != -1)
```

...the warning is because `size_t` is an unsigned type, so it can never actually be -1. In reality, the comparison can succeed, but only because -1 gets converted to a `size_t` before the comparison (in the process becoming the largest value possible for a `size_t`). If you're aware of that, and want it to happen, explicitly casting -1 to a `size_t` will usually eliminate the warning. To be technically correct, it would probably be better to use `std::string::npos` instead of -1 though.

Better still would be to eliminate all of this by (for example) putting your string into a `stringstream`, and extracting words with `operator>>`.

Edit: Since this seems like a somewhat interesting (and common) problem, I decided to write my own version for fun. You'd better not turn this in unless you study it *really* carefully, because I can practically guarantee that any prof seeing this *will* have a lot of questions (and if you give any wrong answers, the question you'll need to work on is "Would you like fries with that?):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

class rev_string { 
    std::string data;
public:
    rev_string(std::string const &input) { 
        data.assign(input.rbegin(), input.rend());
    }
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, rev_string const &r) { 
        return os << r.data;
    }
};

int main() { 
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin),
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
              std::ostream_iterator<rev_string>(std::cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```

Note that there's really a much cleaner way to do this (using `std::transform`), but it's not quite obscure enough looking to guarantee setting off alarms when/if a prof sees it, so I'm not posting it (at least for now).